# Angular 6 Validators.pattern() RegEx Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, validation

I'm trying to use a regular expression with the Validators.pattern() for Angular 6 FormBuilder, but the validation never goes through. I have tested the RegEx on https://codepen.io/devtips/pen/gzqKKP to see if it was accepted and it did.

The expression I wrote is `/^[(0-9)]*[\s][\d]{1,5}-?[\d]{1,5}$/` and the formats I'm trying to validate are `(000) 000-0000` and `(000) 0000-0000` but my input always shows an invalid result.

```
buildAgentDetailsForm() {
this.agentDetailForm = this.fb.group({
  FirstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]],
  LastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]],
  Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  Phone: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^[(0-9)]*[\s][\d]{1,5}-?[\d]{1,5}$/)
    ]
  ],
  EmergencyPhone: ['', [Validators.required]],
  Address: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });
}
```

Is my expression written in a wrong way? Also I'm using a mask on the input field so it will restrict the input and will include the `()` and the dash

Comment: what's the type of your input? Is it simply string? I bet it's not but might be wrong

Comment: @maxime1992 it's a type='text' input, it only recieves a string, should it be something different?

Comment: Umh my bad then. No it's fine. Can you create a quick repro on stackblitz? Might be easier to help you out!

Comment: It really sounds as if there were some typo in the code. However, a more precise pattern would be `/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3,4}-\d{4}$/` (as per your sample strings).

Comment: Your regex matches the example value and you added it correctly. It should work, so I'd double check the real control value (spaces?). Simple way: window['c'] = this.agentDetailForm

Comment: Thank you all, I was making some changes and I do notice that if I remove the mask I have in place (which I made using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) then the RegEx matches if I type the right characters... Don't know what might the problem though since the mask is simply a string I suppose

Comment: I created a stackblitz and test your validation, it's working fine. It must be your masking or other place that cause the error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-q-ng-val. It must

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing pattern validator with this: `Validators.pattern("[(0-9)]*[\\s][\\d]{1,5}-?[\\d]{1,5}")`

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't give me errors or something about the regex string not being valid, but it just seems the input is not matching it, thus not giving me a valid result

Comment: That will make no difference, see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L269-L319